# Lookup in bash with math calculation

Tags: bash

I have a file file1.txt:

```
veg potato 2
fruit orange 4
fruit apple 3
```

Another file file2.txt:

```
   orange 7
   potato 18
   apple 9
   mango 4
   onion 3
```

I want in second column of file1 to lookup in first column of file2 and add a column with math calculation in file 1 as:

file3.txt

```
  veg potato 36
  fruit orange 28
  fruit apple 27
```

I have no idea on using lookup so seeking for help hear. Looking for any pointers.

Comment: please update the question with your bash/while loop attempt

Comment: is every row in `file1.txt` guarantted to have a match in `file2.txt` (and vice versa)? if 'no', please update the question with an example of a non-matching row

Comment: Are both files always guaranteed to be in the same order of fruit or could you have apple then orange in one but orange then apple in the other? If 'no' please update the question with an example of a different order bertween the files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an awk approach that first reads the second file, and stores in an array the second column values indexed by the first column values. Then, it goes through the first file, and multiplies its third column with a stored value from the array, if the second column's value matches its index:

```bash
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} {$3*=a[$2]; print}' file2.txt file1.txt > file3.txt
```

The same approach using `while` loops could be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -A a
while read -r idx val; do
  a["$idx"]="$val"
done < file2.txt
while read -r pfx idx val; do
  printf '%s %s %s\n' "$pfx" "$idx" $((val*${a["$idx"]:-0}))
done < file1.txt > file3.txt
unset a
```

This approach (in both variants) assumes the value `0` (implicitly in numeric contexts in the awk script, explicitly using `:-0` in the bash script), if a reference cannot be resolved, resulting in the calculated product of also `0`. If instead you want to just retain the original value in such cases, add a condition to the awk script by prepending `$3*=a[$2]` with `if ($2 in a)`, or replace `:-0` with `:-1` in the bash script.